# ADO.NET Entity framework model Performance

Tags: c#, database, performance, entity-framework

I saw similar questions around the same topic, but i couldn't solve my issue.

I have asp.net web application with DB2 backend. And we have the entity framework model 3.5
So when i load the page for the very first time, it takes close to 15 seconds for executing the first query. And the query is very simple, selecting a row from one table and the where clauses are indexed. This is the query

```
 protected Detail getProgramDetail(string id1,string id2, string id3)
 {
     Detail result = (from d in context.Detail
            where d.id1.equals(id1) &&
            d.id2.equals(id2) &&
            d.id3.equals(id3)
            select d).FirstorDefault();
     return result;

  }
```

I tried updating the statistics too, but it didnt help either.
After reading other performance tuning articles, i made this query as a compiled one, but still its taking close 15 seconds. But the subsequent calls are pretty fast in milliseconds. I think its taking time to establish the connection and run the query.

Is there a way to improve the initial performance?. I tried to generate views. But i am receiving the below error. Not sure how to handle this one.

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or
>   is not valid

My connection string is in machine.config.

Thanks in advance.
Srividhya

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to improve the initial performance?.

What about it is not ASp.NET / Entity Framework but IIS - STARTING THE APPLICATION, including doing the compilation needed ;)?

Make it hot - there is an extension that can call a page when IIS starts, so the applicatin is hot (compiled, loaded in memory).

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: I did generate views for DB2, it did help my performance but not drastically. As we are still using VS 2008 i am not able to try the compile one. Still need to try the second level caching. – Srividhya 29 secs ago edit

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options which you look forward for solving this issue

1) Add the second level caching with the Entity framework .This article is very helpful
http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/hh394143(en-us).aspx

2) Querying and ORM dont stick together very well ,Can you use a stored procedure and Datareader which will definitely optimize performance.

3)If you can use Optimize the first or default in your code

Comment: I did generate views for DB2, it did help my performance but not drastically. As we are still using VS 2008 i am not able to try the compile one. Still need to try the second level caching.

Comment: @Srividhya have you tried the optimizing the first or default